# how to run multiple microservices in single batch file

Tags: batch-file, microservices

```
start cmd.exe /c
cd C:\Users\abc\projects\eureka-server
mvn spring-boot:run

start cmd.exe /c
C:\Users\abc\projects\API-Gateway
mvn spring-boot:run

C:\Users\abc\projects\spring-cloud-config-server
mvn spring-boot:run

C:\Users\abc\projects\spring-boot-microservice-auth
mvn spring-boot:run

C:\Users\abc\projects\currency-insertion-service
mvn spring-boot:run

C:\Users\abc\projects\currency-exchange-service
mvn spring-boot:run

C:\Users\abc\projects\currency-conversion-service
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I want to run all the microservices application at one single click, when I use above commends, it is running only first service, then after nothing running.

Comment: Why do you use `start`? Wouldn't `call "%UserProfile%\projects\eureka-server\mvn" spring-boot:run` etc. suffice?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple after opening a command prompt window, running `start /?` and reading the output usage help of the internal command **START** of `cmd.exe`:

```
start "Eureka Server" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\eureka-server" mvn spring-boot:run
start "API Gateway" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\API-Gateway" mvn spring-boot:run
start "Spring Cloud Config Server" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\spring-cloud-config-server" mvn spring-boot:run
start "Spring Boot Micro Service" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\spring-boot-microservice-auth" mvn spring-boot:run
start "Currency Insertion Service" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\currency-insertion-service" mvn spring-boot:run
start "Currency Exchange Service" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\currency-exchange-service" mvn spring-boot:run
start "Currency Conversion Service" /D "%USERPROFILE%\projects\currency-conversion-service" mvn spring-boot:run
```

That batch file runs each `mvn` as separate process whereby I don't know what `mvn` is at all as not posted in the question. It would be best to reference the file `mvn` with fully qualified file name which means with drive + path + name + extension enclosed in `"` on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. The file extension would make also clear if `mvn` is an executable (`.exe` or `.com`) or a sort of a script (`.bat` or `.cmd` or `.vbs` or `.js` or ...).

This works of course only if none of the started `mvn` depends on another `mvn` because of `cmd.exe` start them all as fast as possible one after the other for running parallel each with its own console window if `mvn` is a Windows console application or a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to run all the microservices application at one single click, when I use above commends, it is running only first service, then after nothing running."
as you said this is happening because your next microservice path is not find .

```
you can write as in batch file :
                @echo off
                 cd C:\Users\abc\projects\eureka-server
                 mvn spring-boot:run
                 cd ..
                 cd API-Gateway
                 mvn spring-boot:run
                 cd ..
                 cd spring-cloud-config-server
                 mvn spring-boot:run
                 cmd /k

               Or one can run through jar file instead of mvn spring-boot:run by 
               giving path till target folder
              @echo off
              cd  eureka-server\target
              start "tst1" java -jar "jarname"
              cd ..
              cd ..
              cd  API-Gateway\target
              start "tst2" java -jar "jarname"
              cmd /k
```